# Getting separate means line in a single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I'm working on this figure and wondering if it's possible to get a mean line (like the black line in the figure) but for each concentration group.

Sorry I can't share the data with you.
Ideas?

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

p=sns.swarmplot(x="Class", y="DS", data=dfx, size=9, palette="summer_r", hue="Conc")
sns.boxplot(showmeans=True,
            meanline=True,
            meanprops={'color': 'k', 'ls': '-', 'lw': 2},
            medianprops={'visible': False},
            whiskerprops={'visible': False},
            zorder=10,
            x="Class",
            y="DS",
            data=dfx,
            showfliers=False,
            showbox=False,
            showcaps=False,
            ax=p)
plt.show()
```

How it is right now:
[image]

How I want it to be (red arrows are just to catch your attention):
[image]

Comment: If you can't share your data, you should re-write your example to rely on one of the numerous datasets bundled with seaborn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the different `conc` values, and call the dummy boxplot for each of them.

Here is an example using the standard tips dataset:

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, size=3, palette="summer_r", hue="sex")
categories = tips["sex"].unique()
colors = sns.color_palette('summer_r', len(categories))
for cat, color in zip(categories, colors):
    sns.boxplot(showmeans=True,
                meanline=True,
                meanprops={'color': color, 'ls': '-', 'lw': 2},
                medianprops={'visible': False},
                whiskerprops={'visible': False},
                zorder=3,
                x="day",
                y="tip",
                data=tips[tips["sex"] == cat],
                showfliers=False,
                showbox=False,
                showcaps=False,
                ax=ax)
```

[image: sns.swarmplot mean line per hue value]

Comment: Works. Thank you